# Simplest Ajax upload jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm looking to add ajax uploading to my application with a progress bar, but the only solutions I've found seem to be entirely vertically and overly complex. I'll need to do my own styling for basically everything, and I need some custom functionality, so I'm looking for something simple.

My desired behavior is this:

```
1.) User can select a number of files.
2.) User hits "upload" and the ajax upload sends each file one at a time, with independent progress bars.
```

I need an `Add Files` button essentially, and I'm restricted to NO FLASH. I only need to support latest Firefox and Chrome, so IE8 isn't an issue.

What plugins should I be looking at? Non-GPL licenses are preferred.

Comment: Does NO FLASH really mean no flash at all, or just no flash for the interface elements? Unless the newest browser versions have some kind of upload progress support, you'll probably be out of luck. Since you've already looked into some solutions, Uploadify is probably not suitable. I'm curious to see if there's a solution that doesn't rely on flash. +1

Comment: There are plugins which don't use flash, and instead use iframes to do the post. I'm looking for one which suits my needs so I don't need to implement the weird hack myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having ever tried it — http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ seems to do what you want:

Features listed on the site:

- multiple file select
- progress-bar in FF, Chrome, Safari
- doesn't use Flash

Comment: +1 for Valum's Ajax Uploader. I switched to it after headaches with the flash-based Uploadify.

Comment: 1-GPL. 2-it seems like overkill. Digging into the source, it looks like the modifications I need won't be trivial.

Comment: It really isn't. Unless I completely gut all the styling and class modification out of the library, I'm stuck with all kinds of bloat. Everything is handled automatically, and documentation is very weak. I need to disable most of what it's doing.

Comment: I guess then you're probably best off writing your own.

Comment: I guess I'll have to deeply gut the library. What a maintenance issue.

Comment: in IE8 - button on there home page -- not shows up. So not working as a normal production?

Comment: @softm: You might want to open a new question for this problem or post a comment over at http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ .

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: Currently, Valum's Ajax Uploader is licensed under GPL2 and LGPL2.

Comment: As a post-mortem, I *did* wind up deeply gutting the library. It was a pain in the ass, but the end product was nice. Hopefully a number of the bugs have been fixed since my endeavor.